# SQL Server SYS Messages

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Just happened to check on the sysmessages in different versions of MS SQL Server and I observed a difference in the text.

Message ID : 2627

In one of the version(SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM) the Text is : Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '%.*ls'.

and in another(SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1)) the text is : Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls. --> This one gives more details.

Is there any specific document available which can tell me what changes were done to the sysmessages in different versions of SQL.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just run this query on both systems:

```
select * from master.dbo.sysmessages 
where msglangid = 1033
order by error
```

and then compare the two results with WinMerge or any other diff tool? You could also import the results into a spreadsheet and use formulas to find and/or filter differences.

Here's a quick screen cap of a WinMerge Diff of SQL Server 2005 and 2008 R2:

[image: WinMerge Diff of sql server 2005 and 2008 R2]

As you can see by the amount of orange there were many changes between those two versions. Doing this with your particular versions should produce fewer changes.